# How can I add or subtract using case formulas?

Tags: netsuite

I have sales metrics tracking using case formulas to give me a sum when a status is updated in system notes. If you look at the image, what I'm trying to accomplish is to add a column that would show total appointments (first formula) minus the set number of '20'.  I want to see the difference between the sum and the sales target of 20

[image: Case formulas image]

Answer (score 3):

Set the Summary Type to Min and sum the result using the formula. Then you can use arithmetic on the sum.

```
SUM(CASE ... END) - 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your case formula in SUM(your case formula) - 20.
Change NetSuite's SUM to MINIMUM (SUM will work but probably return unexpected results on the Total row)